# How can we add a web link as a button in Google Dialog flow Chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, kommunicate

I want to add a link as a button in google dialogflow chatbot and it was integrated with kommunicate.
Please help me how we add a link as a button.When user clicks that button he has to redirect to another page.[image: Like this i have to add a link as button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below metadata to render the Link Buttons:
Send custom data to bot platform via rich message response

```
{
    "message": "click on the buttons",
    "platform":"kommunicate",
    "metadata": {
        "contentType": "300",
        "templateId": "3",
        "payload": [{
                "type": "link",
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "name": "Go To Google"
            },
            {
                "type": "link",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
                "name": "Go To Facebook",
                "openLinkInNewTab": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Use openLinkInNewTab: false to open any link in the same tab. Default value is true, which will open the links in the new tab.

Comment: If we want these buttons in whatsapp means what i have to do.
And i we want only button without link message means what i have to do.

Comment: `"openLinkInNewTab": false` is not working any solution? or alternative?